# command to replace specific contents of all *.gpl files

Tags: linux, command

I am having this below line in my `*.gpl` file  .

```
#WANTS TO MODIFY REFERENCE_OUTPUT_* HERE IN BELOW LINES
set output "REFERENCE_OUTPUT_fun1.png"
set output "REFERENCE_OUTPUT_fun2.png"
set output "REFERENCE_OUTPUT_fun3.png"
set output "REFERENCE_OUTPUT_fun4.png"
-
-
-
#DO NOT WANTS TO MODIFY REFERENCE_OUTPUT_* FOR BELOW LINE 
plot '/project/subfolder1/REFERENCE_OUTPUT_fun1.txt' u 1:2 w l axes x1y1 ti "Ref output"  lc rgb "red"
```

and I do have minimum 800+ `*.gpl` files in dump folder .

I want to dump my generated output `png` files in separate `images` folder .

So,

I am trying below command to do so :

```
sed -i 's/set output "REFERENCE_OUTPUT_*/set output "./images/REFERENCE_OUTPUT_*/g' {} *.gpl
```

But getting Below Error

**Error**:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 25: unknown option to `s'
```

**Expected Output**:

In all `*.gpl` files this above set output line changes from :

```
set output "REFERENCE_OUTPUT_fun1.png"
```

**to**

```
set output "./images/REFERENCE_OUTPUT_fun1.png"
```

**UPDATE:**

`*.gpl` file also has :

```
plot '/project/subfolder1/REFERENCE_OUTPUT_fun1.txt' u 1:2 w l axes x1y1 ti "Ref output"  lc rgb "red"
```

So in above line `REFERENCE_OUTPUT_fun1.txt` also has name `REFERENCE_OUTPUT_fun1` which I do not want to change . So that's the reason I am using `set output "REFERENCE_OUTPUT_*` which will just modify this `set output . .`  line (in theory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to match entire string - just replace prefixes

```
sed -E -i -u 's/(REFERENCE[a-zA-Z_0-9]+\.png)/\.\/images\/\1/g' *.gpl
```

Comment: I have just updated my question by considering your answer.I do have name `REFERENCE_` two times in *.gpl file .But I just want to change at its first appearance .which is at set output line .

Comment: @jailaxmik I've updated my answer to match only image lines, not every `REFERENCE` prefix